# Pythonic Way of Storing Multiple Set of Lists (same names - different params) to be Called by Functions

Tags: python

I've built a few generalized functions that loop over a set of parameters to help in a price optimisation exercise. Given that each product has a different set of costs inputs the amount of parameters for each can vary. The issue is that each product will have a different set of configs, so I need to store these somehow. To build my quick demo to test my code I just added suffix _1, _2, _3, etc... but now looking for a more structured way to build and maintain it.

```
import pandas as pd

#Configs params - Product 1
factors_1 = ['BaseAmount','Factor1','Factor2','Factor3','Factor4','Factor5']
operation_1 = [None,'x','x','x','x','+']
custom_functions_1 = [None,None,None,None,'custom_function_1(df, 0.15)',None] #To call custom function
rounding_1 = [None,False,True,True,False,True]
rounding_decimals_1 = [None,None,1,0,None,0]

operation_summary_1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(operation_1, custom_functions_1, rounding_1, rounding_decimals_1)),
                    index  = factors_1,
                   columns =['operation', 'custom_functions', 'rounding','rounding_decimals'])
operation_summary_1

#Configs params - Product 2
factors_2 = ['BaseAmount','Factor1','Factor6','Factor5','Factor7']
operation_2 = [None,'x','x','+','+']
custom_functions_2 = [None,None,None,'custom_function_2(df, 0.15)',None] #To call custom function
rounding_2 = [None,False,True,True,True]
rounding_decimals_2 = [None,None,0,0,0]

operation_summary_2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(operation_2, custom_functions_2, rounding_2, rounding_decimals_2)),
                    index  = factors_2,
                   columns =['operation', 'custom_functions', 'rounding','rounding_decimals'])
operation_summary_2
```

What I'm looking for is a recommendation on the best way to store these lists for 100s of products which I would want to load and then iterate on as lists. I was thinking classes could be one good way of storing these, but I don't have much experience with those.

Thinking of doing something like the following, but first not sure how to get it to work and more importantly not sure it's good coding practice.

```
class product_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.factors = ['BaseAmount','Factor1','Factor2','Factor3','Factor4','Factor5']

product_1.self.factors
```

Comment: What about a dictionary? You can store each of your lists in there, and then look them up whenever you need to pull data from one.

Comment: A list of instances of a class, perhaps a `dataclass`, may be a solution, but not defining one class for each product like in your example: just define one class, and pass the set of parameters to each instance you create. It is difficult to say more without more context. For instance, will you need to use `partial` for your `custom_functions`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a data holder, the best you can get is a `dataclass`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

you create one class that describes your data container. Then you call to this class as many times as you need to create new instances, see examples in the link above